# Finding the Most current entry for a month using mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having a mysql problem I am trying to find both the most current payment value, and, for a particular month (in this query I'm using April). Link to the sqlfillde is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eea9d/1)

```
(case when max(py.pay_date)and month(py.pay_date)= 4 then amount else 0 end) max_pay_april,
```

This is what I have but it doesn't seem to be working. The most current payment value is: `(5,    '2012-04-20',    90,)` therefore it would be `90`  I would really appreciate some help please.

Comment: can you show us your completely query?

Comment: the Entire thing is in the sqlfiddle @ElVieejo

Comment: @dames It's still considered good practice to include the relevant bits inline, rather than requiring people to click through to SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
select p.name,
  v.v_name,
  sum(case when Month(py.pay_date) = 4 then amount end) april_amount,

  max(case 
    when month(py.pay_date)= 4 
    and py.pay_date = (select max(pay_date) 
                       from payment 
                       where month(pay_date) =4 )

   then amount else 0 end) max_pay_april,

   sum(case 
        when Month(py.pay_date) = Month(curdate())
        then amount end) current_month_amount,
  sum(case 
        when Month(py.pay_date) = Month(curdate())-1
        then amount end) previous_month_amount


from persons p
left join vehicle v
  on p.id = v.person_veh
left join payment py
  on p.id = py.person_id
group by p.name,
  v.v_name
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eea9d/11)

Comment: Thank you so much, I actully see how powerful mysql is I didn't think about using another select statement.